# copying range using column and row numbers (integer) vba

Tags: vba, excel, integer, range, cells

I've got a standard template. to counteract the fact that users add their own columns I've indexed all the columns. I made a variable for the title header and assigned a integer to this variable.
So column A is always called the string variable `ColumnA` with integer variable  `IColumnA`. I've also got a set number of rows and the variable `LRow` for last row.

My question is:

How can I select a column range with the integer variable?

For instance `range(IcolumnA, lastrow .end (xlUp)).Copy` (or a variant hereof)

This doesn't work because the integers don't work with the range method (I reckon).

Who can help me along?

Answer (score 1):

***Edit:***
This is a general solution of the question "How do I copy ranges". The answer is - declare a source and target and copy the source to the target:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim rngSource   As Range
    Dim rngTarget   As Range

    With Worksheets(1)
        Set rngSource = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(100, "B"))
        Set rngTarget = .Range(.Cells(2, "C"), .Cells(100, "D"))

        rngSource.Copy
        rngTarget.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

If you only want to copy the whole column, try something like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Range(Columns(5), Columns(6)).Copy
    Range(Columns(7), Columns(8)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

It will copy columns 5 to 6 to columns 7 to 8. Of course, instead of numbers you can put variables.

---

And this is a bit more sophisticated, with variables:

```
Sub TestMe()

 Dim lngCopyColumn   As Long: lngCopyColumn = 2
 Dim lngPasteColumn  As Long: lngPasteColumn = 10
 Dim lngLenC         As Long: lngLenC = 3

 Range(Columns(lngCopyColumn), Columns(lngCopyColumn + lngLenC)).Copy
 Range(Columns(lngPasteColumn), Columns(lngPasteColumn + lngLenC)).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
 Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean with LngLenC? Is that the total row count?
k, clear

Comment: @MyName - total Columns in the range. It should be the same for both ranges.

Comment: Thanks. Only thing is it selects the whole column. I need to offset it with 1 from the 1st cell (so from cell 2) to end(xlDown). I tried toying around to little succes. Can you specify where this command needs to go?

`WsStam.Range(Columns(iKolomnrCorpID), Columns(iKolomnrCorpID)).Copy`

Comment: That's unfortunately not what I'm looking for. The range is dynamic which is why I need to use `.End(xlDown)`. I need to be able to use the integer I've assigned to the columns (So that users can add whatever columns they want. The ones used for calculations keep the set number) to copy and paste (if at all possible).

FYI: 've written the macro to copy and paste the stuff I want. Even with different row counts. However it messes up when users have added columns.

Comment: @MyName - declare a variable for `.End(xlDown)` and put it instead of `100`.

Comment: That's not doable (throws all kinds of errors). I'm gonna update my in initial post to clarify it better.

Comment: @MyName - when I say declare a variable for `.End (xlDown)` I mean something like this `dim k as long : k = Range("A1").end(xlDown).row`. Then exchange `k` with `100`.